# Why does assignment has no effect when formal arguments and instance variables are same?

Tags: java, this

I am trying a simple example in java:

```
class student{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    void stud(int id,String name){  
    id = id ;
    name = name;  
    }  
    void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name);}  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
    student s1 = new student(); 
    s1.stud(1,"sss");  
    s1.display();  
    }  
}
```

it gives me an o/p as 0 and null

and the following program :

```
class student{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    void stud(int i,String n){  
    id = i ;
    name = n;  
    }  
    void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name);}  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
    student s1 = new student(); 
    s1.stud(1,"sss");  
    s1.display();  
    }  
}
```

gives me an output as 1 sss

Why does changing the formal parameters to names different from member variables of the class works correctly?

Comment: Short answer: hiding.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you declare a parameter in

```
void stud(int id,String name)
```

you are *hiding* (shadowing) the instance variable `id`. Therefore, whenever `id` is accessed within the method `stud`, it will refer to the *local* `id`, not the instance variable.

If you want to access to the instance variable, use the `this` keyword:

```
void stud(int id,String name) {
    this.id = id; 
    // ...
}
```

`this.id` will refer to the instance variable, while `id` will refer to the parameter (local).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference it using this.id = id; That's because once you pass a parameter with the same name it's a local variable, using this makes it clear you're talking about the classes variable.